# URL-encoded SVGs as background in Edge

Tags: css, svg, microsoft-edge

I created the following pen to demonstrate my problem:
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/mewVGB

I tried to put an URL-encoded SVG image as a background image like this:

```
  background-image: url('data:image/svg+xml;utf8,%3Csvg%20xmlns%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2Fsvg%22%20viewBox%3D%220%200%20500%20512%22%20enable-background%3D%22new%200%200%20500%20512%22%3E%3Cpath%20d%3D%22M258.9%20512c-11.3%200-24.6-2.9-40.5-10.7-10.7-5.2-44.8-22.9-69.7-35.8l-21-10.9c-15.7-8.1-20.2-7.1-32.5.7l-26.9%2017.6c-4.6%203-10.8%201.7-13.8-2.9s-1.7-10.8%202.9-13.8l27-17.6c16.9-10.8%2029.1-13.8%2052.5-1.7l21%2010.9c24.8%2012.9%2058.7%2030.5%2069.2%2035.6%2033.4%2016.3%2048.7%206.6%2066.4-4.5%202.8-1.8%205.7-3.6%208.5-5.2%2017.6-10.2%20146.8-96.1%20159.7-105.3%2014.4-10.2%2017.5-17.6%2018-21.1.2-1.6.3-4.2-2.2-7.4-6.3-8.3-22.3-5.8-43.7%206.9-3.4%202-7.7%201.8-11-.5-3.2-2.3-4.8-6.4-3.9-10.3%201.7-7.5.4-10.4-.2-11.3-.8-1.2-2.4-2-4.9-2.5-7.5-1.5-21.8%201.3-35.6%2010.8-3.4%202.4-7.9%202.4-11.3.1-3.4-2.3-5.1-6.5-4.1-10.6.7-3%201.2-6.9-.7-8.3-5.3-3.9-23.2-1-34.3%205.6-15.2%209.1-69.2%2043.3-69.8%2043.6-4.7%202.9-10.8%201.6-13.8-3.1s-1.6-10.8%203.1-13.8c2.2-1.4%2054.8-34.7%2070.2-43.9%2013.9-8.3%2041.5-15.4%2056.3-4.5%202.5%201.9%205.8%205.1%207.7%2010.1%2012.6-5.5%2025.6-7.7%2036-5.7%208%201.6%2014%205.3%2017.8%2011.2%201.5%202.4%202.7%205%203.4%207.9%2032.1-14%2047.7-2.8%2054.5%206%205.2%206.8%207.3%2014.6%206.1%2022.5-1.8%2011.8-10.6%2023.4-26.2%2034.5-13.5%209.6-142.6%2095.5-161.2%20106.3-2.6%201.5-5.2%203.2-7.9%204.8-11.7%207.6-25.5%2016.3-45.1%2016.3zM300%20422h-58c-28%200-63.3-10-64.7-10.4-5.3-1.5-8.4-7.1-6.9-12.4%201.5-5.3%207.1-8.4%2012.4-6.9.3.1%2034.1%209.6%2059.3%209.6h58c30%200%2030-11.3%2030-15%200-13.1-18.8-15-30-15-25.5%200-73.2-12.3-87.7-21-5.4-3.3-9.6-7.9-14-12.7-11.3-12.2-24-26.2-63.7-26.2-21.2%200-30.4%203.8-42.1%208.6-2%20.8-4%201.6-6%202.5-25.6%2010.2-71.8%2032.3-72.2%2032.5-5%202.4-11%20.3-13.3-4.7s-.3-11%204.7-13.3c1.9-.9%2047.2-22.6%2073.5-33.1%202-.8%203.9-1.6%205.8-2.3%2012.6-5.2%2024.5-10.1%2049.7-10.1%2048.6%200%2066.6%2019.8%2078.4%2032.8%203.5%203.9%206.6%207.3%209.5%209%2011.7%207%2056%2018.1%2077.4%2018.1%2046.4%200%2050%2026.8%2050%2035-.1%2013.1-6.6%2035-50.1%2035zM338.5%20408.9c-3.2%200-6.4-1.5-8.3-4.4-3.1-4.6-1.9-10.8%202.7-13.9l90.3-60.8c4.6-3.1%2010.8-1.9%2013.9%202.7%203.1%204.6%201.9%2010.8-2.7%2013.9l-90.3%2060.8c-1.7%201.2-3.6%201.7-5.6%201.7zM317.1%20373.3c-3.2%200-6.3-1.5-8.2-4.3-3.1-4.6-2-10.8%202.6-13.9l55.7-38.4c4.6-3.1%2010.8-2%2013.9%202.6%203.1%204.6%202%2010.8-2.6%2013.9l-55.7%2038.4c-1.8%201.1-3.8%201.7-5.7%201.7zM348.5%20112.5c-2.2%200-4.3-.8-6-2.5l-86.1-86.1-86%2086.1c-3.3%203.3-8.7%203.3-12%200-3.3-3.3-3.3-8.7%200-12l98-98%2098%2098c3.3%203.3%203.3%208.7%200%2012-1.6%201.7-3.7%202.5-5.9%202.5zM256.5%20290.4c-4.7%200-8.5-3.8-8.5-8.5V16.2c0-4.7%203.8-8.5%208.5-8.5s8.5%203.8%208.5%208.5V282c-.1%204.7-3.9%208.4-8.5%208.4z%22%2F%3E%3C%2Fsvg%3E');
```

In all modern browsers the SVG is displayed. In Microsoft Edge it's not. Is this possibly a bug in Edge?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution to my problem. 
The SVGs were encoded using and old version of grunticon and got their color using the fill property in CSS for dynamic coloring.

Updating grunticon to version 2.0 solved the problem in Edge.

Answer (score 0):

They are actually both working for me.

[image]

can you check out [this jsbin](https://jsbin.com/mowanegiwo/) to let me know if it is not working on your version of Edge?

Comment: Your JSbin is working for me in Edge, but my codepen is not. Only the pink  square is shown, not the icon. I'm on Edge version 20.10240.16384.0